# How to pass on a value after parsing the same elementname a few times

Tags: iphone, xml

I need some guidance about XML parsing. in my case I have to parse XML it looks like

```
<volunteerphotos>
    <event eventid="684"><title>Compton Ave Church of Christ </title>
        <photo>http://www.lafoodbank.org/thumbnailfile.aspx?width=160&path=source/VolunteerEvent/r634382175227818785.jpg</photo>
        <description></description>
        <childphotos>
            <photo>http://www.lafoodbank.org/thumbnailfile.aspx?width=160&path=source/VolunteerEvent/634382175498447249844.jpg</photo>
            <photo>http://www.lafoodbank.org/thumbnailfile.aspx?width=160&path=source/VolunteerEvent/634382175531416421141.jpg</photo>
            <photo>http://www.lafoodbank.org/thumbnailfile.aspx?width=160&path=source/VolunteerEvent/63438217556032304132.jpg</photo>
            <photo>http://www.lafoodbank.org/thumbnailfile.aspx?width=160&path=source/VolunteerEvent/634382175591104685110.jpg</photo>
        </childphotos>
    </event>
    <event eventid="678">
        <title>USC Marshall Business School Community Service Day </title>
        <photo>http://www.lafoodbank.org/thumbnailfile.aspx?width=160&path=source/VolunteerEvent/r634382069855729838.jpg</photo>
        <description></description>
        <childphotos>
            <photo>http://www.lafoodbank.org/thumbnailfile.aspx?width=160&path=source/VolunteerEvent/634382070719490894949.jpg</photo>
            <photo>http://www.lafoodbank.org/thumbnailfile.aspx?width=160&path=source/VolunteerEvent/634382070752616318261.jpg</photo>
            <photo>http://www.lafoodbank.org/thumbnailfile.aspx?width=160&path=source/VolunteerEvent/634382070793554342355.jpg</photo>
            <photo>http://www.lafoodbank.org/thumbnailfile.aspx?width=160&path=source/VolunteerEvent/634382070832304838230.jpg</photo>
            <photo>http://www.lafoodbank.org/thumbnailfile.aspx?width=160&path=source/VolunteerEvent/634382070866680278668.jpg</photo>
        </childphotos>
    </event>
</volunteerphotos>
```

Here, same name tag  is used but i confused how can i stored accessed in next view.
Any suggestion....!!!!

Comment: Maybe a bit of effort in formulating your question would result in a better outcome for you. What do you think?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to do, none of the text you provide is XML.

Comment: I edited your question so i could see the XML, it will be updated once peer reviewed.

Comment: Also, are you developing in Objective-C? which language?

Comment: Do you plan to use *iphone developer* as title for all of your questions?

Comment: which data you want...According to data only you can read that tags..

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I have a feeling this is another one of those people who thought "Title" meant "Job Title" and not "Question Title".

Comment: Aaaaah guys why so mean? xD  I adapted the question to view the XML correctly and changed the title (also added a tag to attract more people). Lets hope the user reads and learns from it. If not, I guess we can rest assured this user will give up quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Something that really helped me in my application, and a lot of other people, is to do [this](http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/) tutorial entirely. It lets you understand the basics of XML parsing.

After doing the tutorial (including programming! No lazy reading only ;) ), try to program the parser into your app.

After that, come back to SO if you still don't understand things.

EDIT: I understand your main problem is to give the (selected) value to another view. In that case, you should set your secondView.value (NSDictionary).